# RegEx Match only first part of URL and use this as variable

Tags: regex, pcre

Always been struggeling with RegEx, help is much appreciated!
I want to match parts of a URL with Regex but cannot get my head around it.

Domains are:

https://**name**.secondpart.thirdpart.com

I want my regex to match

**name**  How would I achieve this?

Started with `(?<=^|\.)` and `(?<=^|\.)secondpart\.thirdpart\.com$` but it didn't work.

Comment: What about `(?<=://)[^./]+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I escaped the slashes using leading backslashes, assuming you use slash as your regex delimiter. If you use no or a different delimiter (e.g. #) you can just use `/` instead of `\/`.

---

If you only care about the first part, then

```
^[^.:\/]+:\/\/([^.]+)
```

should do the trick.

https://regex101.com/r/CXXOOD/1

---

If you for also need to enforce a specific domain after that then capture it in a group like this

```
^[^.:\/]+:\/\/([^.]+)\.secondpart\.thirdpart\.com$
```

https://regex101.com/r/gjfYhC/1

---

If you want to make sure that at exactly 3 parts come after the sub-domain part, but don't care what they are:

```
^[^.:\/]+:\/\/([^.]+)(?:\.[^.]+){3}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/lUYBkT/1

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, Option 1 or 2 would suffice for me. 
How would I exclude that https:// would not be matched?

https://name.secondpart.thirdpart.com should only match name

Comment: `^[^.:\/]+:\/\/([^.]+)` https://regex101.com/r/eVwncn/1 -> the first capture group will be first part (after protocol). Note that I escaped the slashes here, assuming you use slash as regex delimiter. If you use a different one (e.g. `#`) you don't need that: https://regex101.com/r/RkVcbv/1

Comment: Actually, if you escape the backslashes, the look-behind suggestion of Wiktor (in the comment of your question) should work as well ( https://regex101.com/r/BaqL3p/1 ). However, this looks for (`://`) within the entire URL, not just in the beginning. That's *probably* still safe though, if you only process the first match.

Comment: Nice, it works! (https://regex101.com/r/BaqL3p/1) 
`^[^.:\/]+:\/\/([^.]+)`

Thanks so much for your help, guys. Made my day!

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged pcre, you can use:

```
^https?://\K[^\s./]+
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the protocol with an optional s
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^\s./]+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char except `.` and `/`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TDDIh3/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it,

```
(?:http[s]*\:\/\/)*(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})
```